# owl slider questioin. Navigation buttons flickers when hover

Tags: wordpress

Can any one tell me why owl slider's  navigation buttons flickering when hovered?
These are the '+' plus sign images.
http://kmg.makingconnection.co.uk/

Thankyou 'dingo_d'. By doing left:0 & right:0 along with position: absolute solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons have opacity over them at 0.5, and when you hover there is a change in the opacity to 1

```
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-buttons div:hover {
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Because you are using background as a plus sign, every time you are hovering over it you apparently trigger that change that results in a flicker. It's better to use pseudoelements for this (even though when you turn the opacity down you can see a bit of overlap)

```
#owl-demo .owl-prev{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 65px;   
    font-size: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 31px;
    position:relative;
    background:transparent;

}

#owl-demo .owl-prev:before,
#owl-demo .owl-prev:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-4px;
    width:8px;
    height:32px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background: #ED1B34;
    opacity:0.5;
}

#owl-demo .owl-prev:after{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#owl-demo .owl-prev:hover:before,
#owl-demo .owl-prev:hover:after{
    opacity:1;
}
```

[image]